# Is There a Legal Age to Publish a Manga/Comic?

Tags: publishing

Very recently I have thought of the question whether or not publishing a book at a younger age than 18 or 16 was possible, while it is of course possible to do this I began to think whether publishing a manga or comic was possible below a workng age too.

I know these days it's very hard to take a soon-to-be 15 year old very seriously given the state of mind in teenagers these days, and I know some people suggest going to family for advice when starting a big project and, believe me, I have tried, however all I seem to get are 'that's good' or a simple nod of the head which really can be a pain if you're looking for constructive criticism. I have planned to originally start this off as a webcomic, mainly posting it on sites such as DeviantART, but when doing this there is always a threat of someone taking individual pages of your comic/manga without permission and trying to sell it for themselves, which is understandable given how the current generation are too lazy to draw themselves, but I digress.

I know there probably isn't a legal age for this sort of thing and I might just be thinking on this a little too much, but another thing i'm worried about is the self-publishing and the traditional publishing. While I remain top of my class I was never good at marketing or being able to estimate good prices for anything, and it's a pain knowng a family member would have to sign contracts for you, especially if you're going to be using an alias, but i'm getting off-track again. Anyway however, I think that's all I really need to say, i'm guessing you all get the basic idea of what i'm trying to say. Detailed answers would be greatly appreciated.

But one thing before I end this question. I would like to shortly specify what i'm trying to say (or at least attempt at doing so).
   What I mean to say is: I know very many people thnk Manga or Comic writing isn't a real form of writing, and I can understand where they are coming from, but it is still clased as writing, therefor it is a profession. So, in simplifying the question, if there is no legal age to publish these sorts of things then what would be a good age to begin publishing them? Bear in mind however that I would like to publish this in the near future, the near future being a year or two from now.

Comment: What country are you from? Generally, the age should be no problem, but there might be a requirement of having an adult parent/guardian who will sign the papers.

Comment: @Alexander - Well, I was born in Germany but I currently reside in Tokyo. However I speculate that by the time I come to the conclusion that I finally want to attempt publishing this to the world I will have moved to the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to research the relevant laws in your country.

Generally, anyone of any age can publish anything. What minors often cannot do is enter into legal contracts. For example, you will have a contract with your publisher that allows them to publish the work you created, and you may not be of age to sign such a contract, so your parents will have to sign the contract for you. Or if you self-publish, the platforms (Amazon or a blog) may restrict their use to people over a certain age. Again, someone of age will have to use that platform for you.

But there are countless examples of works created by children or adolescents and published, so basically it is possible.